# Zoom not closing properly

Tags: process, ubuntu-mate, kill

I have Zoom installed as a snap.

When I close Zoom, it stays in memory as shown in top.

And if I start it again it just creates more copies in memory.

I then have to

```
killall -9 zoom
```

Is there a fix?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Same issue with macOS aparanntly...